# Is There an HBase 1.2 Equivalent to Accumulo's Authorizations Class?

Tags: security, hadoop, hbase, accumulo

In Accumulo 1.6, there is an [org.apache.accumulo.core.security.Authorizations](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/security/Authorizations.html) class. It basically wraps a collection of authorization strings.

The Authorizations object can be passed to methods such as:

- org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Connector.createScanner(String, Authorizations)
- org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Connector.createBatchDeleter(String, Authorizations, int, BatchWriterConfig)

Does HBase 1.2 have a similar concept?

- None of the constructors of org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan takes an argument of a type that's an obvious counterpart to Accumulo's Authorizations class.
- None of the createConnection methods of org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory takes an argument that's an obvious counterpart to Accumulo's Authorizations class.

What is the HBase equivalent to org.apache.accumulo.core.security.Authorizations, if any?

Comment: Hwo about: https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase.tags

Answer (score 0):

HBase's API for interacting with cell-labels is significantly different. There are no direct analogies between the two implementations.

But, to try to guess, you're probably looking for [VisibilityClient](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/security/visibility/VisibilityClient.html).

Answer (score 0):

After finding this page -- https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/hbase_cell_security -- I *think* I've found *most* of what I'm looking for.

HBase has an org.apache.hdoop.hbase.security.visibility.Authorizations class that seems to be an approximate equivalent to Accumulo's Authorizations class. This class is used in places like:

- org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get.setAuthorizations(Authorizations)
- org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setAuthorizations(Authorizations)

What I've not yet figured out is *how to make HBase actually apply Authorizations when working with cells having visibility settings* -- that is, for cells created via org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation objects (through the Put sub-class) for which setCellVisibility(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.visibility.CellVisibility) method had been invoked.

It seems HBase ignores visibility/authorizations logic by default.